# longblob performance storage for lots of records

Tags: mysql

app_files table

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| file_id   | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| file_data | longblob     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I add 10,000 images to this table and lookup images based on file_id, will the performance 
suffer?

I already know it is NOT recommend to store files in the database, but I need this to work with backups in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the performance will be good, since you're querying on Primary Key, which is already indexed.
However, if you plan to do query on file_name, don't forget to create an index on that field.
And don't do queries on file_data :)